# How to correctly set time format in strftime method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, time, format, strftime

I have the following method

```
 <%= message.created_at.strftime("%H:%M") %>
```

that currently returns **21:00**

I need to display a Europe/Kiev time zone which is 3 hours ahead than usual Greenwich's time zone. How do I set it in the method input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stored time in your database in UTC than that time will always be in UTC when you fetch it. You need to display it according to user's local time zone. You have to do that using JavaScript, check this [article](http://www.nikolatodorovic.com/nikolas-blog/rails-4-postgresql-timezone-best-practice).

Or if you need just Kiev time zone and nothing else you can do something like this:

```
<%= message.created_at.in_time_zone('Europe/Kiev').strftime("%H:%M") %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a beautiful gem named "local_time". It takes care of local rendering of the time in your views. It has very nice documentation as well. Visit https://github.com/basecamp/local_time